# joomla 1.5 display flash object

Tags: joomla1.5

how do i display a flash swf file in a joomla article ?

I installed jce editor but the flash embed plugin is not free. Is there a alternative method where i can easily embed swf files in artiles ?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to put flash embeded code in article html. Just toggle editor and paste the code. 
you can get free component and plugin from

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/flash-management